# regex search digit or digit and space to length of search term in js. In this case, 3-5 characters, if there are spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

me find the values "ddd", "dsdd", "ddsd" from the list below: "**150** EUR **15 0**00 EUR **150** **150** EUR **1 50**0 EUR".

I tried:

```
/(\d{3})|(\d+\s\d{1,2})/gm
```

The result of the test: (The bold value should not be matched)

- 150
- 15 0**0**
- 150
- 150
- 1 50

Comment: That is `\d+(?: \d+)?` or `\d+(?:\s\d+)?`

Comment: `\b\d\s?\d\s?\d` https://regex101.com/r/gTmpvn/1 or `\b\d(?:\s?\d|\d\s)\d` https://regex101.com/r/D4hmDJ/1

Comment: You have updated the question a few times, does the pattern work?

Comment: Hi, yes, thanks! How can I mark yours as the correct answer? This is my first time using this for a side question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of your alternation `\d+\s\d{1,2}` matches only a single whitspace char only once, and `\d+` matches 1 or more digits and `\d{1,2}` match one or 2 digits.

To match 3 digits, with either a whitespace char between the first and second, or second and third digit, or match 3 digits only:

```
\b\d(?:\s?\d|\d\s)\d
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\s?\d` match an optional whitspace char followed by a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `\d\s` Match a digit followed by a whitspace char
- `)` Close the group
- `\d` Match a digit

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D4hmDJ/1)